# ms access how to refer with VBA to a sub report in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, subreport, refer

I have a form with inside a sub-report. In a module, I need to refer to the sub-report text field but I have no idea how to do?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?
Forms!frmMain!frmSubform.Form.RecordSource

Comment: The subform is not a FORM but a REPORT so how do you adapte your code considering this. Thanks